# Elasticsearch- get all values for a given field?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to query for all of the values a specific field? Say I have "articles" and each  article has an author, is there a query I can perform to find a list of all authors?

Comment: This can help :[Query all unique values of a field with Elasticsearch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26647301/1145750).

Comment: The selected answer is pretty out-dated. pls refer [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466274/query-all-unique-values-of-a-field-with-elasticsearch)

Comment: FYI the selected answer has changed since @MohanKumar made their helpful comment above.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

> ## **How to get all possible values for field `author`?**

```
curl -XGET  http://localhost:9200/articles/_search?pretty -d '
{
    "aggs" : {
        "whatever_you_like_here" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "author", "size":10000 }
        }
    },
    "size" : 0
}'
```

Note

- `"size":10000` Get at most 10000 unique values. Default is 10.
- `"size":0` By default, `"hits"` contains 10 documents. We don't need them.
- By default, the buckets are ordered by the `doc_count` in decreasing order.

---

Reference: [bucket terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

Also note, according to [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets.html), facets have been replaced by aggregations in Elasticsearch 1.0, which are a superset of facets.

Comment: I am using an aggregation when I filter on multiple condition. Is it possible to have values that don't match my filter as a 0 count ?

Answer (score 25):

I think what you want is a faceted search. Have a look at this example from the documentation:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/index.html

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/articles/_search?pretty=true" -d '
  {
    "query" : { "query_string" : {"query" : "*"} },
    "facets" : {
      "tags" : { "terms" : {"field" : "author"} }
    }
  }
'
```

See if you can tailor this to work for you.

Comment: Just a quick note. When searching for all, prefer the matchAll Query.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. I had looked at facets, but thought they were really for counts, I didn't realize I could get terms from them as well. This is actually really awesome, thanks!

Comment: listen to @dadoonet, avoid using wildcards as they negate the value of using a fancy inverted-index like elasticsearch.

Comment: Just a note (for people as me that come here by Google search and don't immediately see that this good answer is a bit outdated): I just learnt that ES 1.4 deprecates facets by aggregations... so refer here: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html

Comment: @PierpaoloCira In addition to the documentation you linked, here is also a nice answer with an up-to-date example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26647301/1666398. Ftr: I like the [`?search_type=count` param](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html#_returning_only_aggregation_results) a lot :)

Comment: It has been mentioned already that facets were replaced by aggregations in ES 1, but in ES 5 they seem to have removed the ability to get all results for an aggregation, so we seem to be back to square one, not knowing how to get all terms...

Comment: @Trejkaz My updated answer should be able to retrieve up to 10000 unique values for one field. If more is needed, [configuration changes may be necessary](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html)

Comment: Error 400 in Elasticsearch 7.3

Answer (score 3):

another example

request

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/_search?pretty=true" -d '
{
  "facets" : {
    "tags" : { "terms" : {"field" : "network.platform"} },
    "size" : 60
  },
  "size" : 0
}
'
```

response

```
{
  "took" : 266,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 650,
    "successful" : 650,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 41,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "facets" : {
    "tags" : {
      "_type" : "terms",
      "missing" : 15,
      "total" : 26,
      "other" : 0,
      "terms" : [ {
        "term" : "platform name 1",
        "count" : 20
      }, {
        "term" : "platform name 2",
        "count" : 6
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention the Elasticsearch Version, but for ES 1.6, the preferred method is using aggregations.  Here is an example of what I use.

--Get all the STATUS values, which is a nested query.

```
GET path for data/_search?size=200
{
  "aggs": {
    "something": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "NESTED_PATH"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "somethingCodes": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "NESTED_PATH.STATUS",
            "size": 50
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and an example Response:

```
"aggregations": {
      "panels": {
         "doc_count": 5029693,
         "panelCodes": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
               {
                  "key": "M",
                  "doc_count": 1943107
               },
               {
                  "key": "W",
                  "doc_count": 137904
               },
               {
                  "key": "E",
                  "doc_count": 69080
               },
               {
                  "key": "Y",
                  "doc_count": 4081
               },
               {
                  "key": "N",
                  "doc_count": 1063
               },
               {
                  "key": "T",
                  "doc_count": 483
               },
               {
                  "key": "",
                  "doc_count": 1
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the optimal way is to use **elasticsearch aggregation**
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

```html
GET {index}/{type}/_search
{
  "size": 0, <-- to not display search hits
  "aggs": {
    "{aggregation_name}": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "{filed_value}",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way of checking existing field values:

```
GET myindex/mytype/<id>/_termvectors?fields=Product.Material.Code
```

- `myindex` = index
- `mytype` = type
- `<id>` = document id

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code to get only list of 'articles' field values from all the content in the index.

curl 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/_search?pretty=true&_source=articles'

It will sure help you.

Comment: Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure with your [answer link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259)
 While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.
 [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: While this may work, using an aggregation would be better since this will return at most 10k docs, not 10k *distinct* values.