# Query all unique values of a field with Elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch

How do I search for all unique values of a given field with **Elasticsearch**?

I have such a kind of query like `select full_name from authors`, so I can display the list to the users on a form.

Answer (score 19):

You could make a [terms facet](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/terms-facet.html) on your 'full_name' field. But in order to do that properly you need to make sure you're not tokenizing it while indexing, otherwise every entry in the facet will be a different term that is part of the field content. You most likely need to configure it as 'not_analyzed' in your mapping. If you are also searching on it and you still want to tokenize it you can just index it in two different ways using [multi field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/multi-field-type.html).

You also need to take into account that depending on the number of unique terms that are part of the full_name field, this operation can be expensive and require quite some memory.

Answer (score 16):

For Elasticsearch 1.0 and later, you can leverage `terms aggregation` to do this,

query DSL:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A real example:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "full_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "authors",
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can get all unique values of `authors` field.
size=0 means not limit the number of terms(this requires es to be 1.1.0 or later).

Response:

```
{
    ...

    "aggregations" : {
        "full_name" : {
            "buckets" : [
                {
                    "key" : "Ken",
                    "doc_count" : 10
                },
                {
                    "key" : "Jim Gray",
                    "doc_count" : 10
                },
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

see [Elasticsearch terms aggregations](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html).

Comment: what does full_name mean ?

Comment: @neustart47 full_name is just the name of aggregations

Answer (score 6):

**Working for Elasticsearch 5.2.2**

```
curl -XGET  http://localhost:9200/articles/_search?pretty -d '
{
    "aggs" : {
        "whatever" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "yourfield", "size":10000 }
        }
    },
    "size" : 0
}'
```

The `"size":10000` means get (at most) 10000 unique values. Without this, if you have more than 10 unique values, only 10 values are returned.

The `"size":0` means that in result, `"hits"` will contain no documents. By default, 10 documents are returned, which we don't need.

---

Reference: [bucket terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

Also note, according to [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets.html), facets have been replaced by aggregations in Elasticsearch 1.0, which are a superset of facets.

Comment: Works for `OpenSearch` also! In 2024.

Answer (score 6):

**Intuition:** 
In SQL parlance:

`Select distinct full_name from authors;`

is equivalent to

`Select full_name from authors group by full_name;`

So, we can use the grouping/aggregate syntax in ElasticSearch to find distinct entries.

Assume the following is the structure stored in elastic search :

```
[{
    "author": "Brian Kernighan"
  },
  {
    "author": "Charles Dickens"
  }]
```

**What did not work:**  Plain aggregation

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "full_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "author"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**I got the following error:**

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default...",
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**What worked like a charm:**  Appending ***.keyword*** with the field

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "full_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "author.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**And the sample output could be:**

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "full_name": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "doc_count": 372,
          "key": "Charles Dickens"
        },
        {
          "doc_count": 283,
          "key": "Brian Kernighan"
        }
      ],
      "doc_count": 1000
    }
  }
}
```

**Bonus tip:**

Let us assume the field in question is nested as follows:

```
[{
    "authors": [{
        "details": [{
            "name": "Brian Kernighan"
          }]
      }]
  },
  {
    "authors": [{
        "details": [{
            "name": "Charles Dickens"
          }]
      }]
  }
]
```

Now the correct query becomes:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "full_name": {
      "aggregations": {
        "author_details": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "authors.details.name"
          }
        }
      },
      "nested": {
        "path": "authors.details"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The existing answers did not work for me in Elasticsearch 5.X, for the following reasons:

- I needed to tokenize my input while indexing.
- `"size": 0` failed to parse because "[size] must be greater than 0."
- ["Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default."](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/fielddata.html) This means by default you cannot search on the `full_name` field. However, an unanalyzed `keyword` field can be used for aggregations.

**Solution 1**: use the [Scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html). It works by keeping a search context and making multiple requests, each time returning subsequent batches of results. If you are using Python, the elasticsearch module has the [`scan()` helper function](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#scan) to handle scrolling for you and return all results.

**Solution 2**: use the [Search After API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-after.html). It is similar to Scroll, but provides a live cursor instead of keeping a search context. Thus it is more efficient for real-time requests.

Comment: I'm not sure this works around the "size":0 problem, because the default as far as I can see from the docs is 10...

Comment: scroll does not work on python es client 2.2. it will throw the exception `elasticsearch2.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'aggregations are not supported with search_type=scan')`