# Getting documents by aggregated list of Id's from previous query in Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

So I've got a database of metadata of video material. lets call each video an `asset`.

so each `asset` has a type, this can be for example `movie` or `episode`.

each asset also has a collection of `tags`. Tags are stuff like genre, promotions, etc.

Tags are not a nested type, in fact assets only has a string referencing a tags `id`

Tags are stored in a separate collection.

Now my task is, for a given `type` of `asset`, return a set of all `tags` assigned to any `asset` within that `type`.

This will apparently then be used to generate a UI, meaning every enduser will make this request when they load our page/app, so this has to be as fast as possible.

So what I've come up with is essentially the naive approach, namely getting all assets filtered by `type`, instructing Elastic to only return the `tags` field, and then fetch the tags in a second request basically concatenating all the `tagid`'s together with an `or` between them.

I've been reading into aggregations, thinking if it's similar to MongoDBs aggregation framework I should probably be able to make this faster, but so far I've come up short.

is there any way to accomplish this in a single request to ElasticSearch?
I should mention here I'm stuck using version 1.7.5, so no new fancy-pants features are available to me.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466274/query-all-unique-values-of-a-field-with-elasticsearch Also, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html this page on **term aggregation** talks about extracting unique field values. Looks like you just need a filter before doing the aggregation.

Comment: If you're looking for an answer with code - what exactly is the type of `tags`? Is it a JSON array like `["family", "drama", "comedy"]`? Or simply a string like `"family drama comedy"`

Comment: its an array..I've been reading through the link you posted but have not been able to discern a way to solve this issue from it...any further pointers?