# OpenSearch syntax to fetch all the distinct values in a field

Tags: grafana, opensearch

How do i extract all the distinct values from a field in opensearch?
I am trying get list of all the distinct names using following:

`{"find": "terms", "field": "first_name"}`

I also want to utilize the same syntax in grafana to create a variable.

Comment: See doc https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-opensearch-datasource/
that's not possible because "Query will use current dashboard time range as time range for query."

Answer (score 0):

To get all distinct values from a field in opensearch you can make use of bucket aggregations as described in their documentation:
https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/aggregations/bucket-agg/#terms

Also have a look at this post:
[Elasticsearch- get all values for a given field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384736/elasticsearch-get-all-values-for-a-given-field)